# Error finding CACerts on the relative path in the CACertPathList option of IDaaSOIDCStrategy in passport-ci-oidc on Cloud Foundry

Tags: passport.js, openid-connect, cloud-foundry, relative-path

I attempted to create an IDaaSOIDCStrategy. In the options I specify a relative path for the CACerts that begins with "/", in my case "/local/".

```
  const Strategy = new openIdConnect.IDaaSOIDCStrategy(
  {
    ...
    addCACert: true,
    CACertPathList: [
      '/local/<certificate-name>.pem',
      '/local/<another-certificate-name>.pem',
  }
```

The path is supposed to be resolved relative to the app root. However, when I deployed the app to Cloud Foundry, it crashed with an error that the first file in the `CACertPathList` couldn't be found:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory

Instead of looking under the app root,the strategy creation code is looking under the root folder of the **passport-ci-oidc** package, which is where **node_modules** is installed. In my Cloud Foundry deployment, the root folder of **node_modules** is not the app's root, it's in a different place, under `/home/vcap/deps/0/`. The app root is in `/home/vcap/app`.

What can I do to ensure that the path of the CACerts is resolved properly?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is a workaround, but a resolution nonetheless. (The behavior of the strategy code in which it finds the relative path from the root of the **passport-ci-oidc** package does not match the description in the documentation, which states that it uses the app root, so it may be a defect).

When Cloud Foundry builds dependencies, if there is a **node_modules** directory under the app root, it will find it, and look for dependencies there, instead of creating a **node_modules** directory in another location.

In my case, I had originally included **node_modules** in the **.cfignore** file, so **node_modules** was not being pushed to Cloud Foundry. When I removed **node_modules** from **.cfignore**, the local **node_modules** folder, which is under the app root, is pushed directly under the app root. As a result, the root of the **passport-ci-oidc** package is the same as the app root, so the relative path is expanded from the app root.